# How to avoid race condition with unique checks in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, validation

I have a simple model:

```py
class InvitationRequest(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

And a simple model form:

```py
class InvitationRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InvitationRequest
```

Now, assuming that I attempt to process it in a standard way:

```py
form = InvitationRequestForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

There is a race condition because validation performs a simple `SELECT` query to determine whether or not such email is already stored, and if everything is fine then it proceeds to `form.save()` line. If there is a concurrent process that does the same at exactly the same moment, then both forms will validate and both processes will call `form.save()` thus one will succeed and the other will fail causing an `IntegrityError`.

**What is the standard way to handle this?**

I want to have a standard error in the form object so I can pass it on to the template and notify user about the problem.

I know that:

- I can wrap everything with try/except and add new error to my form manually
- I can wrap everything with `SERIALIZABLE` transaction (in MySQL as it performs next key locking fo every select then)
- I can use override `Model._perform_unique_checks` and make
  it use `select_for_update` (works with MySQL because of next key locking)
- I can acquire table-level exclusive lock

None of these solutions is appealing, also I am using PostgreSQL which differs from MySQL in this area.

Comment: I'm not a big user of Django, but maybe something like this will help out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20682954/1270148

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way is to NOT handle this, as:

1. the probability of the failure in your case is close to 0;
2. the severity of the failure is very low.

If, for some reason, you have to be sure that the problem won't happen, you are on your own.

I haven't analyzed the sequence of events in detail but I think that using the SERIALIZABLE isolation level won't really help, it will only cause `IntegrityError` (or `DatabaseError`) to be raised in a different place.

Overriding `Model._perform_unique_checks` sounds to me like a bad idea, you better stay away from monkey patching if possible (and here it *is* possible).

As for using the table lock to prevent unlikely errors... Well, I'm not a big fan so I cannot recommend that either.

Here's a nice answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523439/176186 - I concur that catching `IntegrityError` and retrying is probably the easiest sane way to deal with the problem.

EDIT: I found this: [Symfony2 - how to recover from unique constraint error after form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589216/symfony2-how-to-recover-from-unique-constraint-error-after-form-submission) and I agree with @pid's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Tomasz Zielinski that common practice is to not worry about this. For most use cases it's just not worth the trouble.

If it *is* important, the best way is probably with optimistic concurrency. In this case it might look like (untested):

```
from django.forms.util import ErrorList

def handle_form(request)
    form = InvitationRequestForm(request.POST)
    try:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(...)  # redirect to success url
    except IntegrityError:
        form._errors['email'] = ErrorList()
        form._errors['email'].append('Error msg') 

    return render(...)  # re-render the form with errors
```

`SERIALIZABLE` won't really help here. As the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html) makes clear, you have to be prepared to handle serialization failures, which means that the code would look pretty much the same as above. (It *would* help, though, if you didn't have the `unique` constraint forcing the database to throw an exception.)